# How to change SysVinit service without editing init script?

Tags: linux, sysvinit

Let assume a service is `xyz`. In systemd, the `/lib/systemd/system/xyz.service`
file has this command:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xyz --foo
```

I want to add `--bar` option in that command. With systemd, I can add these
following lines in `/etc/systemd/system/xyz.service.d/xyz.conf` drop-in file:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xyz --foo --bar
```

This can override the command after `systemctl daemon-reload`. I want to this
same in SysVinit but *without* editing `/etc/init.d/xyz` file. Is it possible
to add/change command options without editing that SysVinit script? If not then
what is the proper way? I want to change that command option permanently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On systems that still rely on SysVInit, you need to know what is the mechanism that your specific distribution adopts. Since you can `source` any file inside your daemon scripts, it's up to the distribution to decide where the default configs will be.

Quoting a [post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/the-directory-etc-default-723942/#post3531173) from Slackware forum:

> My understanding is that this is a Debian concept that has been
>   adopted by a few packages.
>
> Basically, `/etc/default` contains some parameters that the end user or
>   administrator is likely to change, rather than embedding the values in
>   the actual boot scripts. In this way, changes will persist even if you
>   upgrade the package and the boot script is replaced.
>
> The concept is essentially the same as the `.conf` files under `rc.d`
>   (`rc.inet1.conf`, `rc.bluetooth.conf`, etc), but they are in one
>   centralized location away from the scripts themselves.

Means that, mostly Debian based distributions use `/etc/default`.

On [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/ch-sysconfig) based distros, you will find that this kind of configuration is managed by the `/etc/sysconfig` directory on the most common softwares(`acpid`, `httpd`, `ntpd`, `crond`, `samba`).

On Arch, before the systemd switch, you used `/etc/{rc.conf,rc.d/functions,rc.d/functions.d/}` to customize daemons.

[On Slackware](http://www.slackware.com/config/init.php), depending of the service you will have the `.conf` file inside `/etc/rc.d/` with the same name of the daemon you want to give parameters to(`rc.inet1.conf`, `rc.wireless.conf`...), or you have to edit the daemon file itself.

**tl,dr:** There is no "default SysV Init" parameter file or directory.